# Unit Testing in XCode (Obj C) With MVVM

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, dependency-injection, viewmodel

I'm testing out some MVVM pattern stuff and seem to have gotten myself confused. Hoping someone here can clarify things for me.

So, what I did was set up a project and added a class that is a subclass of NSObject and called it RootViewModel.

Gave it one method:

```
- (void) rootTest {
    NSLog(@"Booyeah!");
}
```

In ViewController I imported RootViewModel and made an IBOutlet for it.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RootViewModel.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnRunModel;
@property IBOutlet RootViewModel* myModel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myModel rootTest];
}

@end
```

Then in Storyboard I dragged an Object into the ViewController scene, named it RootModel and connected it to the myModel property in ViewController.

[image]

Run the app and it works as expected, Booyeah gets logged.

So now here's where I got messed up. I wanted to set up a unit test. So working in the default unit test file I imported ViewController and made it a property and instantiated it in the set up.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ObjectiveVMMVTests : XCTestCase

@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController* myViewController;

@end

@implementation ObjectiveVMMVTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    self.myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Then I tried to create a test where I call the rootTest method.

```
- (void) testRootModel {

    [self.myViewController.myModel rootTest];
}
```

But I get a compiler error saying myViewController has no property myModel. I assumed it would be there, not sure where I messed this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your unit test, you are saying:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

That's great. So now the unit test knows that this is a class. But that is *not* where the `myModel` property is declared. It is declared in *ViewController.m*, making this a private property.

Move the property declaration into *ViewController.h* to make it public so the unit test can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @matt said, the IBOutlet is not part of the public interface of `ViewController`. It's private, hidden in the implementation (`.m`) file.

You have at least two viable options:

1. Add `@property IBOutlet RootViewModel* myModel;` to the `ViewController.h` file to make it part of the public interface;
2. Add an interface definition to the `ObjectiveVMMVTests` unit test file that'll satisfy the compiler:

   ```
   @interface ViewController ()
   @property IBOutlet RootViewModel* myModel;
   @end
   ```

The implementation of the `-(RootViewModel*)myModel` getter is there anyway, the compiler just needs to know that `ViewController` does respond to the message. (You could use `performSelector` if you weren't interested in the returned object.)